# get error "fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree" when trying to do git status

Tags: git, github

I got a newbie question. I'm trying to do git status in the `.git` folder, and git returns the error

> `"fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree".`

I have searched for a solution, but I could not find one specific for this problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%22fatal%3A+this+operation+must+be+run+in+a+work+tree%22

Answer (score 2):

The `.git` folder is a special folder that stores all information about your repository.

You don't run any git commands inside it. You run the git commands in your repository folder (parent of the `.git` folder).